# Set cache-control header for a specific sub-folder inside statics folder

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I've a `static` folder with this structure,

```
└── static
    ├── images
    ├── locales
    └── robots.txt
```

I've set `location` directive for this folder to cache the files publicly.

```
location /static {
    access_log        off;
    log_not_found     off;
    expires           1y;
    autoindex         off;
    add_header        Cache-Control "public";
}
```

I want to change the `Cache-Control` header to `public, stale-while-revalidate=60, stale-if-error=60` for all the `json` files that are inside **locales** folder.

I've tried nested location but without success,

```
location /static {
    access_log        off;
    log_not_found     off;
    expires           1y;
    autoindex         off;
    add_header        Cache-Control "public";

    location /static/locales/.*/.*\.json$ {
         expires      1w;
         add_header   Cache-Control "public,stale-while-revalidate=60, stale-if-error=60";
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I was really close to the solution, all I needed is to add `~` in front of the regex at the nested location,

This works!

```
location /static {
    access_log        off;
    log_not_found     off;
    expires           1y;
    autoindex         off;
    add_header        Cache-Control "public";

    location ~ /static/locales/.*/.*\.json$ {
         expires      1w;
         add_header   Cache-Control "public,stale-while-revalidate=60, stale-if-error=60";
     }
}
```